# Google Script working as 2 separate scripts but not inside the same function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, data-structures, formatting

Basically I have a script that is in 4 blocks:
1. Copies within a range each row provided it meets a criteria
2. Removes all empty rows
3. Sets all numbers as percentage
4. Applies conditional cell formatting to one of the columns

The 4th part is the one that is causing me issues. The script runs without any error message AND block 4 works perfectly fine if it's in another script alone with the same variables defined but as soon as it is inside the same function as the others it simply doesn't run without any error message of any kind.

Tried changing the name of the variables to single use ones to ensure it wasn't because one of the "var" was modified above it, removing the "else if" to keep only an "if" in the loop, moving it around to other parts of the script but if the block 1 is in the script then block 4 won't apply (will apply if it is only with 2 & 3.

2 & 3 which follow the same structure work well with 1.

Does any one have any clue what's wrong with my script ? :) 
Each block is commented with what it does

```
function copy() {
//Set variables & criterion to choose which rows to copy
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bEiLWsbFszcsz0tlQudMBgTk5uviyv_wDx7fFa8txFM/edit');
  var ssSource = s.getSheetByName('Variations');
  var ssDest = s.getSheetByName('Email');
  var lastRowSource = ssSource.getLastRow();
  var lastRowDest = ssDest.getLastRow();
  var lastColSource = ssSource.getLastColumn()
  var criteria = 0;
  var titles = ssSource.getRange(1,1,1, lastColSource).getValues()


//Copies the range
  ssDest.getRange(1,1,1, lastColSource).setValues(titles)

  for (var i = 2; i < lastRowSource; i++ ) {
    var test = ssSource.getRange(i ,1);    
    Logger.log(test.getValue()+ ' <? ' + criteria);
    if (ssSource.getRange(i ,6).getValue() > criteria) { 

      ssSource.getRange(i ,1,1,ssSource.getLastColumn()).copyTo(ssDest.getRange(i ,1,1,ssSource.getLastColumn()), {contentsOnly:true}); // copy/paste content only
}  
    }

//Removes empty rows
  var data = ssDest.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetData = new Array();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,'')!=''){ targetData.push(data[n])};
    Logger.log(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,''))
  }
  ssDest.getDataRange().clear();
  ssDest.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);

//Formats numbers as percentages
  var rangePercent = ssDest.getRange(1,1,ssDest.getLastRow(),ssDest.getLastColumn());
  var rowsPercent = rangePercent.getNumRows();
  var colsPercent = rangePercent.getNumColumns();

  for(var rowPercent = 1; rowPercent <= rowsPercent; rowPercent++) {
    for(var colPercent = 1; colPercent <= colsPercent; colPercent++) {
      var cellPercent = rangePercent.getCell(rowPercent, colPercent);
      var valuePercent = cellPercent.getValue();
      if(typeof(valuePercent) == 'number') {
        cellPercent.setNumberFormat("##.#%");
      }
    }
  }

//Adds conditional background colours

  for (var z = 2; z < lastRowDest+1;z++) {
    var avgCpc = 4;
    var rangeColour = ssDest.getRange(z,avgCpc);
    var dataColour = rangeColour.getValue()
    if (dataColour < 0) {
      ssDest.getRange(z,avgCpc).setBackground('#d9ead3')
      }
            else if (dataColour > 0) {
        ssDest.getRange(z,avgCpc).setBackground('#f4cccc')
      }

  }

//Centers Values

}
```

Comment: Try inserting SpreadsheetApp.flush() after block three.

Comment: Could you please provide a spreadsheet with some dummy data? It will make easier to find the cause of your issue.

Comment: Hi @Cooper this does not work unfo

Comment: Hi @albertovielma my company is very strict in data sharing so my access level prevents me from  sharing any file with an email address that's not registered as the company's...

Comment: Well, then I guess I can't help you. I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Hi again @albertovielma I managed to work around it using my personal account here is the dummy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ckE6tLsXwEROI_JjrN68RCCDyw90VjQ9eQJVn1v7bco/edit?usp=sharing
I've also included the script with the new link in the last tab thanks for your help sorry for the back and forth

Comment: @MaximeIvan, don't worry, thank you for sharing the spreadsheet, I couldn't have helped you without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is your code has performance issues because you're calling too many times methods such as [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) inside various loops, therefore Apps Script can't keep up with all those calls. Please check [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Having said that, I modified your code in order to make it more efficient. Besides your `copy` function, I added two more functions to make the code more readable.

### function copy

As before this function sets the variables, but now it calls two other functions, which are `setPositiveCostValues` and `formatCells`

```
function copy() {
  //Set variables & criterion to choose which rows to copy
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('your-url');
  var ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('Variations');
  var ssDest = ss.getSheetByName('Email');
  // set the title
  var titles = ssSource.getRange(1,1,1, ssSource.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  ssDest.getRange(1,1,1, ssSource.getLastColumn()).setValues(titles);
  // get the positive values you want from the cost col
  var positiveValues = setPositiveCostValues(ssSource, ssDest, ssSource.getLastRow());
  // fomrat the cells you want as percentage and set the color
  formatCells(ssDest, positiveValues);
}
```

### function setPositiveCostValues

This will take the values where the cost is positive and it will get rip off of the cells with empty values and "n/a" values.

```
function setPositiveCostValues(ssSource,ssDest, lastRowSource){
  var postiveCost = ssSource.getRange(2, 1, lastRowSource, 6).getValues();
  // this loop will clean the empty elements and the ones that only have n/a
  for (var i = postiveCost.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (postiveCost[i][0]) {
      postiveCost.splice(i + 1, postiveCost.length - (i + 1));
      postiveCost = postiveCost.filter(function(el){ return el != 'n/a'})
      break;
    }
  }
  return postiveCost;
}
```

### function formatCells

This will format the cells in the cost col as a percentage and will set the right color in your avgCpc col.

```
function formatCells(ssDest, postiveCost){
  var avgCpc = 4, cost = 6, row = 2, criteria = 0;
  // iterate over the array and depending on the criteria format the cells 
  postiveCost.forEach(function(el){
    if(el[cost - 1] > criteria){
      var ssDestRange = ssDest.getRange(row, 1, 1, cost);
      ssDestRange.setValues([el]);
      ssDestRange.getCell(1, cost).setNumberFormat("##.#%");
      // set the color depending on the avgCpc value condition
      if(el[avgCpc - 1] < criteria) ssDest.getRange(row, avgCpc).setBackground('#d9ead3');
      else ssDest.getRange(row, avgCpc).setBackground('#f4cccc');
      row++;
    }
  });
}
```

### Code

Your whole code now it will look like this:

```
function copy() {
  //Set variables & criterion to choose which rows to copy
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('your-url');
  var ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('Variations');
  var ssDest = ss.getSheetByName('Email');
  // set the title
  var titles = ssSource.getRange(1,1,1, ssSource.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  ssDest.getRange(1,1,1, ssSource.getLastColumn()).setValues(titles);
  // get the positive values you want from the cost col
  var positiveValues = setPositiveCostValues(ssSource, ssDest, ssSource.getLastRow());
  // fomrat the cells you want as percentage and set the color
  formatCells(ssDest, positiveValues);
}

function setPositiveCostValues(ssSource,ssDest, lastRowSource){
  var postiveCost = ssSource.getRange(2, 1, lastRowSource, 6).getValues();
  // this loop will clean the empty elements and the ones that only have n/a
  for (var i = postiveCost.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (postiveCost[i][0]) {
      postiveCost.splice(i + 1, postiveCost.length - (i + 1));
      postiveCost = postiveCost.filter(function(el){ return el != 'n/a'})
      break;
    }
  }
  return postiveCost;
}

function formatCells(ssDest, postiveCost){
  var avgCpc = 4, cost = 6, row = 2, criteria = 0;
  // iterate over the array and depending on the criteria format the cells 
  postiveCost.forEach(function(el){
    if(el[cost - 1] > criteria){
      var ssDestRange = ssDest.getRange(row, 1, 1, cost);
      ssDestRange.setValues([el]);
      ssDestRange.getCell(1, cost).setNumberFormat("##.#%");
      // set the color depending on the avgCpc value condition
      if(el[avgCpc - 1] < criteria) ssDest.getRange(row, avgCpc).setBackground('#d9ead3');
      else ssDest.getRange(row, avgCpc).setBackground('#f4cccc');
      row++;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alberto - With my limited knowledge I would have never found the solution :)